# array bit parameter range in verilog - underflow or -1

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, hdl, modelsim

What should be index ranges of parameter `init` in this case:

```
parameter zero = 0;

parameter bit[31:0] size = 32'b01;

parameter bit[((zero * size) - 1):0] init = 2'b11;
```

It should be `[-1:0]` or `[4294967295:0]` and why? Is such behavior standardized or it depends on tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the LRM, the range in an array declarations are signed integer expressions. It should cast the 32-bit unsigned expression to a signed integer. So the result is -1. You can test this by displaying the result of `$left(init)`

Whether all tool developers have read the LRM is another question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful. Could you quote a part of the specification or pinpoint the chapter treating about it?

Comment: Section 6.9.1says: "Both the msb constant expression and the lsb constant expression shall be constant _integer_ expressions". This text is unchanged from the Verilog LRM and the _Integer_ type is signed.